# ActionScript 3 FlxG.keys error

Tags: actionscript-3

So I have more errors like these:

Player.as(21): col: 25 Error: Access of undefined property FlxG.

on this code:

```
    override public function update():void
    {
        super.update();
        velocity.x = 0;

        var right:Boolean = (FlxG.keys.RIGHT || FlxG.keys.D);
        var left:Boolean = (FlxG.keys.LEFT || FlxG.keys.A);
        var up:Boolean = (FlxG.keys.UP || FlxG.keys.W);
```

how can I fix it?

also I am begginer to actionscript3 and I don't know too many terms. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FlxG it is a Flixel Class. To fix this issue you should download [Flixel](http://flixel.org/download.html) library and place org folder near your FLA file.

Comment: Oh no, I fugured out what happend. I forgot to import org.flixel.* into my class. What a fool am I! :)